# To show $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Show that if $f$ is a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathbb{C}_\infty-f(\mathbb{C})$ has at least three points then f is constant.

I constructed a new function $g$ such that $g(z) =f(z)$ if $z$ is not a pole of $f$ and $g(z) = \infty$ if $f$ has a pole at $z$. Then clearly $g$ is entire function and misses at least two points.So by the little Picard Theorem.$g$ must be a constant,so is $f$.
 Am I correct ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Picard's Theorem is not applicable to your $g$ since it takes the value $\infty$.

Comment: Say the 3 (finite) values missed by $f$ are $a,b,c$, let $g(z) = 1/(f(z)-a)$,  it is entire and misses $1/(b-a), 1/(c-a)$

Comment: No, $g$ is _not_ an entire function.